# Laravel records entity wrong

Tags: mysql, laravel

There are entity and on recording to database, record wrong data

Code to record entity

```
public function createTelegramUser($entity)
{                                                   
    TelegramUser::create($entity);
}
```

Entity

```
[entity] => Array
    (
        [telegram_id] => 5403205983
        [is_bot] => 
        [first_name] => Belarus
        [username] => dilshodbelarus
        [language_code] => ru
        [message] => /start
        [context] => 
    )
```

Database record

[image]

Look at `telegram_id`, on entity `5403205983` but on database `1108238687`

**Details:**

Table `telegram_users` structure

[image]

field `telegram_id` is `varchar(255)`

Model `TelegramUser`

```
<?php
namespace App\Models\API;
use App\Traits\TraitUuid;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class TelegramUser extends Model
{
    use HasFactory, TraitUuid;
    protected $fillable = ['telegram_id', 'is_bot', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'language_code', 'status'];
    protected $attributes = ['status' => 1];
}
```

TraitUuid

```
<?php
namespace App\Traits;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
trait TraitUuid
{
/**
 * Override the boot function from Laravel so that
 * we give the model a new UUID when we create it.
 */
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    $creationCallback = function ($model) {
        if (empty($model->{$model->getKeyName()}))
        {
            $model->{$model->getKeyName()} = Str::uuid()->toString();
        }
    };

    static::creating($creationCallback);
}

/**
 * Tell laravel that the key name is a uuid, not an id.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getKeyName(): string
{
    return 'uuid';
}


/**
 * Override the getIncrementing() function to return false to tell
 * Laravel that the identifier does not auto increment (it's a string).
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function getIncrementing() : bool
{
    return false;
}


/**
 * Tell laravel that the key type is a string, not an integer.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getKeyType() : string
{
    return 'string';
}
}
```

Data came from telegram `webhook`, Entity dump

```
$request = file_get_contents('php://input');
$request = json_decode($request, TRUE);
$message = $request['message'];
$entity = [
        'telegram_id' => $message['from']['id'],
        'is_bot' => $message['from']['is_bot'],
        'first_name' => $message['from']['first_name'],
        'username' => $message['from']['username'],
        'language_code' => $message['from']['language_code'],
        'message' => $msg['msg'],
        'context' => $msg['context'],
    ];
TelegramUser::create($entity);
```

Comment: yes, I have `protected $fillable = ['telegram_id', 'is_bot', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'language_code', 'status'];`

Comment: with some `telegram_id` it works fine

Comment: @JSTECH with some `telegram_id` it works fine, dont know why

Comment: Because `telegram_id` saves on database perfectly same as on `$entity` variable. And yes, `telegram_id` is unique.

Comment: May be you have written code something if telegram_id is duplicate then generate new one.

Comment: @JSTECH field `telegram_id` on migration `$table->integer('telegram_id')->unique('telegram_id');`

Comment: @JSTECH I dont have any code to generate new `telegram_id`

Comment: Please provide more information or code, so that we can debug it.

Comment: @DilshodIsmoilzod, Should you not use `$table->bigInteger('telegram_id')`?

Comment: From telegram hook came updates, I get updates and record it to database, thats all. But on recording with some `telegram_id` its recording wrong `telegram_id`

Comment: @RobBiermann I changed field to string `$table->string('telegram_id')->change();` but same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone for response, problem was in memory limit, in my `php.ini` file it was `64MB`, thats how number is long this why it sets how many bytes does not enough.

there are two solution change `php.ini`

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');
```

or covert integer to string

```
'telegram_id' => (string) $message['from']['id'],
```

Comment: I'm happy you got it sorted, was quiet a troubleshoot haha

Comment: If you could upvote my answer for at least spotting the overflow issue, that would be nice :)

Answer (score 0):

You have 100% an overflow issue. Ironic, because this is stack-overflow

Max int in mysql = 2147483647

Your input = 5403205983

Your result = 1108238687

If you add 1 to 2147483647, it will become -2147483647
if you try to store 5403205983, it will result in:

5403205983-(2147483647*2) = 110823869(the fact that it is off by 2 is probably me overlooking something here, but it is too similar to ignore)

You say you made the column a string.
I think you did add it to the migration, but did not migrate it.
Please make the column type bigInt or string, verify the column is actually bigInt or string, and retry your code :)

Comment: I migrated it, look to my updated question

Comment: Thanks for that :) Are you using php at 64 or 32 bit?

Comment: @DilshodIsmoilzod run `php -v` to see your version and or `echo phpinfo();` on your browser, since this might use another php version

Comment: Checked, its `x86_64`

Comment: @DilshodIsmoilzod As a test, can you try to run something like this directly into mysql please: `insert into telegram_users(telegram_id,is_bot,first_name,username,language_code,message) values(5403205983, 1, 'test','somename', 'someuser', 'somelanguagecode', 'somemessage')`

Comment: recently inserted, it works fine, every record is perfectly as inserted data

Comment: Then I would like to ask you to show your complete `TelegramUser` model please. If normal mysql statements work fine, we can be assured there is something happening to the number in the php layer, now we just need to figure out where

Comment: @DilshodIsmoilzod Thanks for letting me know :) Can you also show `TraitUuid` please?

Comment: updated question, check it

Comment: @DilshodIsmoilzod Thanks for the update. All I can see is that everything looks fine. We know the database supports the number. We can see that nothing is modifying the number in the model and trait.  Just to be clear, your `entity` dump is done where in the code? In the `createTelegramUser($entity)` function or higher up?

Comment: check updates on question pls

Answer (score 0):

For use cases like this you could use bigInt i don't see a point to be a text record if u expect only numeric values (maybe i'm wrong but on these examples it is all numeric). Or you could pass how long data should be upon creating records in database like:

```
$table->bigInt('telegram_id',10)->unsigned()->unique();
```

Comment: Yes like this I also tried, but not helps, migration code `$table->bigInteger('telegram_id')->change();`

Comment: check phpmyadmin and see if it was applied on table. If it is, this should be able to support longer number, from code that i provided u should be able to do max 9223372036854775807... So way more than that. If this is the case, i can assure you that this is no longer database related issue.

Comment: yes, now its `varchar(255)` its support long numbers

Comment: my point is - it shouldnt be. it should be bigInt with 10 numbers. apply solution as provided.

Comment: if I add by `insert` its working correctly, even inserting more that 10 digits

Comment: why are u not applying solution as provided?
my guess here is that this one: [telegram_id] => 5403205983 is treated like an integer. You can typecast it or do migration as i provided so that it would be supported integer value (bigInt).